# HCMGIS on QGIS not showing I am on ver 3.34.2

Tags: qgis

I have the plugin HCMGIS, has reinstalled it a few times but still doesn't work - I select google maps and shows in the legend as a layer but there are no visuals on the console. Please see screenshot below.[image]

Comment: Your scale and coordinates seem wrong, could you try to right-click the layer and click "Zoom to Layer(s)".

Comment: Hi Kalak - tried that. I also tried creating a new profile with the hope of overriding whatever settings I could have messed up.

Comment: I don't see any other layers in your screenshot.  If you open a project and add some layers with a known CRS, then add Google Maps does that work?  What if you first change the project CRS to the Google Maps CRS, then add your layers and Google Maps?  There is an xyz layer for Google Maps that works well: https://mt1.google.com/vt/lyrs=m&x=%7Bx%7D&y=%7By%7D&z=%7Bz%7D